# Should I use if statement? If yes, what will be good in this PHP case?

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

When I use function create_category(), it will create a directory with this name such as  images/newfolder.

Then I have a function edit_category() which checks post('name').

In a controller

```
function edit_category($id=0){
if ($this->input->post('name')){
...
...
```

I don't want to allow to change the category name. It will create another directory with a new name, images/newfolder2 etc.

In a view

```
$data = array('name'=>'name','id'=>'catname','size'=>25, 'value' => $category['name']);
echo form_input($data) ."</p>";
```

I used the following. but it does not use if ($this->input->post('name')){, so it does not work.

```
echo "<h2>".$category['name']."</h2>";
```

Do you have any good ideas to solve this problem?

--UPDATE--

I am using Codeigniter, but I don't think it is relevant in this case. I want to use if statement or some checking mechanism for this.

Comment: Could you please edit the title of your question to something that is more descriptive? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language is this?  It looks to me like PHP.  Is that what this is?

Comment: I can't think of a descriptive title at the moment. Do you have one?

Comment: I don't understand the question exactly.  Make you question more specific.  Such as I am seeing Error X, why am I seeing error X?  Or if what you really are asking is how should I write this code, then write it up in pseudocode, and say, this is what I want to do.  Such as this:

for every chunk in data, tell me what the name of the chunk is, change all letters to uppercase, process data using a smoothing filter algorithm, append newly processed data in a new array.  Something like this would get you some better answers than my attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use form_hidden() for your name.

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="johndoe" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is enough information on this question to answer it, but my theory is you have the if statement to check if post('name') exists.  If it does not work when you check this statement, it might give you an error.  What error does it give you?

If it gives you an error like unknown member 'name' in $category, then it is because $category['name'] is not being set.  Examine the code the code that sets $category['name'], and determine why it is not being set.

You should add in the error that you are receiving as well.  It would help to understand what type of issue you are having.